# If $p$ is a prime and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that $\binom{pm}{pn}\equiv\binom{m}{n}$ mod $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, binomial-coefficients

Hint: Compare the binomial expansions of $(1+x)^{pm}$ and of $(1+x^m)^p$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $R$ is denoted by $R[x]$.

$\mathbb{I}_p[m]$ is the integers mod $m$.

When $p$ is a prime, we will usually denote the field $\mathbb{I}_p[x]$ by $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

My question: What's the meaning of the hint?

Comment: This idea is used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) for a proof of a more general result.

Comment: I think the hint was meant to say $(1+x)^{pm}$ and $(1+x^p)^m$. The two are the same since $(1+x)^p=1+x^p$ in $\mathbb F_p$. Doing binomial expansions then does the trick

Answer (score 0):

for $a,b\in \Bbb F_{p}$ and $n\in \Bbb N$ you can write $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} a^kb^{n-k}$. The hint is to compare $(1+x)^{pm} = \sum_{n=0}^{pm}{pm  \choose n}x^n$ to $(1+x^m)^p= \sum_{n=0}^p {p \choose n}(x^m)^n$.

Comment: See Wojowu's comment (who meant $(1+x)^p=1+x^p$ in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$)